# #Bluemix: JA018 oozie while running Pig script

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud, oozie

While I am running pig script on Bluemix through oozie I am getting error code `JA018` and error message

```
Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]
```

I researched and found that the jar files should be in directory `/user/oozie/share/lib`

In my case the jar files are in `/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20150622105825.`

Is this causing an issue? Please guide me.

Comment: Hi Alex, When I am submitting Oozie job am getting the Error code: JA018 and Error message: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]. I have changed the sharelib location lib : oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath to /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20150622105825 and set the use.system.libpath = true, but still I am getting the error message. Can you please help.